# How to avoid code smell "too many parameters"

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to register a new doctor and have a lot of parameters to pass. How to avoid code smell "too many parameters" in this case? Not using destructuring on the method!?

```
interface ICreateDoctor {
  name: string;
  crm: string;
  phone: string;
  mobile: string;
  address: {
    zipCode: number;
    street: string;
    number: number;
    city: string;
    state: string
  }
}

@injectable()
class CreateDoctorUseCase {
  constructor(
    @inject('DoctorsRepository')
    private doctorsRepository: IDoctorsRepository;
  ) { }

  async execute(data: ICreateDoctor): Promise<Doctor> {

  }
}

export { CreateDoctorUseCase };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"too many parameters" code smell may be relevant when you are passing many arguments to a function/method.

For instance, something like

```golang
func createDoctor(name string, crm string, phone string, mobile, string, zipCode number, street string, number number, city string, state string)
```

because it is easy to mix up parameters when many accept the same type.

In your case, you have already defined an interface for `ICreateDoctor` with a set of parameters that are required to create a doctor instance, which needs to be done at some point, so it seems fine to me. Callers will only need to pass around `ICreateDoctor`

```golang
func createDoctor(doctor ICreateDoctor)
```

While not necessary to do so, you could define a separate iface/model for address itself, and associate it with the `ICreateDoctor` instance.